# in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) hreres my code

Tags: python, bots

class AmazonBot:
def **init**(self):
# Create a browser we can play on
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install())

```
def log_on(self):
    """First, we must log into our Amazon account"""
    # Go to Amazon
    self.driver.get('https://amazon.com')
    sleep(2)
    # Log in
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a[2]/span[1]').click()
    # Enter email
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/div/div[1]/input[1]').send_keys(email)
    # Continue
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/div/div[2]/span/span/input').click()
    # Click keep me signed in
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/label/div/label/input').click()
    # Enter password
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(2)
    # Authentication will be required, click continue
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('continue').click()
    # Amazon will send you an SMS to verify you are the one using the account
    sleep(6)  # Wait a bit for the message to appear on your computer screen
    # Use the OCR to get the 6-digit Auth code and continue onto your account
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-input-text').send_keys(screen_shot() + Keys.RETURN)

    # Now I have logged onto my Amazon account
    sleep(2)

# This method buys all the stuff
def purchase(self):
    items = ["asus 3070 tuf", "msi 3070 gaming", "msi 3070 ventus 2x oc", "evga 3070 xc3 ultra", "asus 3070 strix", "ZOTAC 3080 Trinity OC WHITE", "evga 3080 xc3 ultra", "gigabyte 3080 gaming oc"]  # Replace this with whatever you want to buy
    for i in range(0, len(items)):  # The for loop that does your shopping
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input').send_keys(
            items[i] + Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).